# post ajax data to spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

I am a newbie to AJAX and i am trying to configure a simple method to post data into the controller using ajax only since i'm not sufficient in `JSON`
,`lambda expressions` other than `Java` can someone tell me what is the mistake i'm doing that this ajax method is not working?

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addCart(int val1, int val2) {
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + val1);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + val2);

    return "redirect:/viewResult";

}
```

**Ajax/Script**

```
 $(document).on('change', '._someDropDown', function (e) {
       var x = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
       var y = $(this).data('idtest');
       alert(x);
       alert(y);

   $.ajax(
        {
         url: "/HRS/test",
         data: {val1: x, val2: y},
         method: 'POST'
         });
  });
```

note that these alerts(x and y values) are shown correctly.I just want to send them to my controller.Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make your `Controller` accept a `POST Request` which your AJAX code would be sending.

Then you need to add a [RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) Annotation over the POJO that you wish to accept from AJAX.

Let's say you need to send `var x, y`. Create a class like this:

```
public class MyData {
  String x;
  String y;
  // getters/setters/constructor
}
```

Then you need to create MyData in your AJAX Call & pass it.

```
 $(document).on('change', '._someDropDown', function (e) {
 var myData = {
  "x" : this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text,
  "y" :$(this).data('idtest')
 }
 .ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType : 'json',
  url: "/HRS/test", //assuming your controller is configured to accept requests on this URL
  data: JSON.stringify(myData), // This converts the payLoad to Json to pass along to Controller
  success :function(result) {
   // do what ever you want with data
 }
});
```

Finally your controller would be something llike:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addCart(@RequestBody MyData data) {
  System.out.println(data.getX());
  System.out.println(data.getY());

  return something;
}
```

My knowledge is a bit rusty but I hope you get the idea how this works!

Comment: Ah yes i got a good idea of doing the above.Thank you very much for your time